# Printing documents using templates

Tags: c++, linux, qt4

Is there a way in Qt4 for Linux of printing documents by templates (like in Windows .xlt and 
.dot)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a bit of an apples to oranges question.  .xlt is a file format for Excel and Qt is a programming platform.  .dot is a file format like .html that can be used by any number of programs that support that file format. I'm not really sure what exactly you mean.

This is a pretty broad question because templates can mean a lot of different things.

```
QString title = "Hello, World!";
QString s = "<html><head><title>"+ title +"</title></head></html>"
```

Might be construed as a template of sorts because you can insert variables into a string and really only syntactically different from:

```
<html><head><title><%=title%></title></head></html>
```

Perhaps what you are really asking is if you can create documents programmatically, to which the answer is yes.  See the [QTextDocument documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/QTextDocument.html) and maybe lookup how to [print to a PDF](https://wiki.qt.io/Handling_PDF).